# Without Lebesgue

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Everyone knows following problem.
Let $f$ be positive function on $[0,1]$ and there exist $I = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$. Prove that $I>0$. (recall that there are only two cases: $I=0$ or $I>0$. NOT $I<0$!!!!)

My question is how to prove it without word "Lebesgue"?? I'm interested in "simple" proof.

**Original proof.**
let $I=0$. Let $A_{n} = \{x: f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}$. It is clear that Lebesgue measure of $A_{n}$ is 0. Let $A=\{x: f(x) > 0\}$. Than $A=A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup ...$ and of course measure of A is 0. That means that f almost everywhere equals to 0. Contradiction with $f>0$.

Comment: Start with simple functions (piecewise constant) and generalize to an arbitrary positive function. This technique is called the standard machine.

Comment: Don't you mean continuous? there is a ton of counter-example of functions which are discontinuous for which I=0. If you mean continuous and you know that $f$ is at least strictly positive on $x=x_0$ then consider a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and apply the definition of continuous.

Comment: Are you considering Riemann integrals only?

Comment: f may be discontinuous. could you give me at least one counterexample?)

Comment: riemann only .
should i recall original proof??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we assume that you're considering Riemann integral, which is equivalent to Darboux integral.

Suppose that $\int_a^bf=0$ and $f\ge0$, we'd show that $\exists x\in[a,b],f(x)=0$. Suppose $I$ is a closed interval, and $\int_I f=0$. By definition of Darboux integral, given $\epsilon>0$, there's a partition $x_0<x_1<\dotsb<x_n$ such that $\sum_k(x_k-x_{k-1})\sup_{x_{k-1}\le x\le x_k}f(x)\le\epsilon\lvert I\rvert$, therefore we can obtain some $k$ such that $\sup_{x_{k-1}\le x\le x_k}f(x)\le\epsilon$. Let $I'=[x_{k-1},x_k]$, we have $\int_{I'}f=0$ and $\sup_{x\in I'}f(x)\le\epsilon$.

Thus we can obtain a sequence of shrinking closed intervals $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq\dotsb$ such that $\int_{I_k}f=0$ and $\sup_{x\in I_n}f(x)\le1/n$.

Now let $x_0\in\bigcap_j I_j$, and we can conclude that $f(x_0)=0$.

**Remark:** If we can take advantage of some tools in measure theory, the proof should be easy. Note that $f$ is measurable. $0=\int_I f\ge\alpha\cdot m(f\ge\alpha)$ hence $m(f\ge\alpha)=0$ for each $\alpha>0$, hence $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: exactly what i want!!

Answer (score 1):

since f is positive . the function $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ is an increasing funcion . and so since $0\leq F(x)\leq \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt.$
If $I=0 $ then necesarly $F(x)=0 =>... f=0.$

Comment: why $F(x) = 0$ implies $f=0$?